# Create a threshold for binary classification problem based on distribution of criterion

Tags: distributions, matlab, exponential-distribution, beta-distribution

I created a criterion for my financial data-set for classify data to two classes for other processing (like `neural network binary classificatio`). After calculating this criterion (between 0 and 1) the distribution of output is like `exponential` (but between `0` and `1` - something like `beta distribution`). Now i want set a `threshold`to create two classes from these samples.

I can set every threshold (`70% - (0.7)` was good in `classification accuracy`) but I want i want a logic for that. for example in `normal distribution` we can set `68–95–99.7 rule`. I want set this default value in my program because different samples are inserting in my system in the feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that your criterion estimates the probability of correct classification and it's not biased. I.e., if the criterion is 0.6, then the probability of correct classification is 0.6. Then, the appropriate threshold will still depend on your loss function. E.g. if you gain \$1 when you classify the case right and lose \$1 when you misclassify then it's enough to set the threshold at 0.51 to win on average. If you gain \$1 and lose $5, then the threshold should be much higher. This reasoning also assumes that you get to make a lot of predictions and you only care about the aggregate result.